# cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to 'byte[*,*,*]'

Tags: c#, window, desktop, face-recognition

```
 Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
            Image<Bgr, byte> grayImage = new Image<Bgr, byte>(bitmap);
            Rectangle[] rectangles = cascadeclassifier.DetectMultiScale(grayImage, 1.2, 1);
            foreach(Rectangle rectangle in rectangles)
            {
                using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                {
                    using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.OrangeRed,1))
                    {
                        graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rectangle);
                    }
                }
            }
```

i have problem at code here:

`Image<Bgr, byte> grayImage = new Image<Bgr, byte>(bitmap);`

the error is at  *(bitmap)*

the error is :
`Error  CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to 'byte[*,*,*]'`

Comment: Are you using Emgu.CV version 4.1.0.3420? The code works for me using that version of Emgu.

Comment: Thanks a lot i got the answer.

Answer (score 7):

For Version 4.3, use:

```
var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
Image<Bgr, Byte> img1 = bmp.ToImage<Bgr, byte>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the frame you get from eventArgs is actually a bitmap? Just because you cast it as such it is not converted to one if its not.

Try using:

```
eventArgs.Frame.Clone() as Bitmap
```

and check it for null.

Also, please post the Frame grabbing method for reference.

Comment: i have try your recommendation but still not working.

the error is still same.

how can i post frame grabbing method?

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade to [EmguCV 4.1.1.3497](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Emgu.CV/4.1.1.3497) for the following code!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after using the latest library (4.4.0.4099).
Here is what I did to solve my problem instead of downgrading.

```
// Create The Bitmap Object From EventArgs.
using (Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone())
{
    // Define A File Path.
    string filePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), DateTime.Now.ToString("ddmmyyyyhhmmssfff") + ".jpg");

    // Lock The Bits In Memory.
    BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);

    // Create OpenCV Image<TColor,TDepth> Object And Add The bitmapData Properties Like So.
    using (Image<Bgr, byte> grayImage = new Image<Bgr, byte>(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height, bitmapData.Stride, bitmapData.Scan0))
    {
        // Get The Rectangles That Should Be Detected From The Training Data.
        Rectangle[] rectangles = CascadeClassifier.DetectMultiScale(image: grayImage, scaleFactor: 1.2, minNeighbors: 1);

        // Unlock The Bits So We Can Draw To It.
        bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

        // Loop Each Rectange In The Retanges Collection.
        foreach (Rectangle rectangle in rectangles)
        {
            // Create Graphics Object And Load The Bitmap From The Beginning
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))

            // Create A Pen, Choose Any Colour
            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Brushes.Red))
            {
                // Draw The Rectange Onto The Bitmap.
                graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rectangle);
            }
        }

        // Create A File Stream And Save The Modified Bitmap
        // We're Using The Above FilePath.
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            bitmap.Save(fs, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
    }

    // Open The Saved Image That Should Contain The Drawn Rectangle.
     System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filePath);
}
```